# Is it possible to use PDOStatement with the Cassandra PHP driver?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, cassandra, datastax-php-driver

I'm trying to use in PHP Cassandra with this Driver: https://github.com/datastax/php-driver.

So, I want to know if is it possible to use to use `[PDOStatement::fetch]` (https://www.php.net/manual/fr/pdostatement.fetch.php) and `[PDOStatement::rowCount]` (https://www.php.net/manual/fr/pdostatement.rowcount.php) with Cassandra without any problem EXACTLY like it possible to use these **PDO Functions** with MySQL?

Comment: The whole point of PDO is that all the methods work the same regardless of the database.

Comment: All right. Thank for your return.

Answer (score 0):

One likely needs to use a "PDO driver implementation for Cassandra CQL" ...
alike this one here: https://github.com/Orange-OpenSource/YACassandraPDO

Only then PDO would be able to produce CQL syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe `PDOStatement` will work out of the box with the Cassandra PHP driver.

Years ago (around 2011), there was a Cassandra PDO driver available on Google Code which worked with Thrift -- https://code.google.com/archive/a/apache-extras.org/p/cassandra-pdo.

It was forked by Orange to provide CQL support -- https://github.com/Orange-OpenSource/YACassandraPDO. However, the last release was all the way back to 2014 and it doesn't look like there has been any work on it since 2015.

As a side note, the Cassandra PHP driver has been in maintenance mode for a number of years now with [the last release (v1.3.2) going back to 2017](https://github.com/datastax/php-driver/releases/tag/v1.3.2). Although we continue to accept pull requests from contributors, I wouldn't recommend doing any new project that uses this driver given it has not been in active development for years. Cheers!